# Selenium script is to identify and run in existing web screen

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is it possible to make Selenium run on already open window? I think, that is possible in Selenium IDE. But application which I am working can run only in IE. So can I write Selenium script to run on already opened IE window? Example, Google is already opened in IE, my script should just search in that screen? Please advise. I am new to selenium, learning by my own to implement in project I am working.

Thanks,
Abdul Hameed

Comment: No signatures please. Read FAQs!